# How to position an android widget

Tags: android, android-layout, widget

this is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

The result is this , the textview is right and next to it (on the left side) is imageview
I want to change it , I want to show the image on the right side and the text on the left side

What should I do ? I tried everything that I know and they didn't work 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Swap them in the xml file. Place the TextView before the ImageView.

Comment: Ok. To be clear what you want is for both of the items to be right alight but to have control over the ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I removed the layout attributes for relative layouts, since you are using a linear layout. Also the gravity attributes were not necessary (per your question, at least). Finally, use 'sp' for text, not 'dp'.